# How to use wait in java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am working on implementing concurrency in Java.  I have two threads one that will count up to 20 and one that will count down from 20.  I want the first thread to finish and then run the second one.  I am able to do this by using the thread.sleep  command but then the second thread runs at a much slower pace than the first.  Is there a way to have the first thread run and then the second thread run at the same pace?  Thank you for any help.

```
import java.lang.*;



public class threads extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        addition addrunner = new addition();
        addrunner.start();
        addrunner.setName("addition");

        subtraction subrun = new subtraction();
        subrun.setName("subtraction");
        subrun.start();
    }

}

class addition extends Thread{
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i<=20; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + i + " - Thread name is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }
    }
}


class subtraction extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 20; i>= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + i + " - Thread name is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: search for `Thread::join`

Comment: And why would you want to use threads to perform a sequential operation?

Comment: There are a lot of these questions on SO.  Typically @SimpleSi they are because of a stupid academic thread class problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `Thread.sleep()` call in the second `subtraction` thread as that is not the correct way of controlling thread execution in your case.

You need to use **[`Thread.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--)** after you start the first `addition` thread, so that the `main` thread will wait until the `addition` thread has completed fully and only then the `subtraction` thread will be started.

```
public class Threads extends Thread{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Addition addrunner = new Addition();
            addrunner.start();
            addrunner.setName("addition");
            addrunner.join(); //main thread waits here, until the addition thread has finished executing

            Subtraction subrun = new Subtraction();
            subrun.setName("subtraction");
            subrun.start();
        }catch (InterruptedException ie){
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class Addition extends Thread{
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i<=20; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + i + " - Thread name is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }
    }
}


class Subtraction extends Thread{
    public void run() {
        for(int i = 20; i>= 0; i--) {
            System.out.println("Number: " + i + " - Thread name is: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Number: 0 - Thread name is: addition
Number: 1 - Thread name is: addition
Number: 2 - Thread name is: addition
Number: 3 - Thread name is: addition
...
Number: 19 - Thread name is: addition
Number: 20 - Thread name is: addition


Number: 20 - Thread name is: subtraction
Number: 19 - Thread name is: subtraction
...
Number: 3 - Thread name is: subtraction
Number: 2 - Thread name is: subtraction
Number: 1 - Thread name is: subtraction
Number: 0 - Thread name is: subtraction
```